# My vbox shared mount will not auto mount and is only ready only?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, centos, mount

My vbox shared mount will not auto mount and is only ready only?

I am using scientific linux host and centOS guest and I am trying to share a folder I have in both accounts but the folder is only reading only.

It will not auto mount then its only read-only.

if I run the following command as root it mounts but only read-only

```
mount -t vboxsf share /home/jsmith/share
```

you can see from the photo below I also have it setup in vbox
[image]

Please I have the following in my /etc/fstab file

```
share                   /home/jsmith/share      vboxsf  auto,rw,uid=1000,gid=1000       0 0
```

Can someone please help me